# Insert or update data with Django formsets

Tags: python, django, django-forms

it's not clear to me how to manage formsets in Django. This is my views.py:

```py
def newAd(request):
    newAdFormSet = modelformset_factory(Ad)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = newAdFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return render_to_response('conf.html',
                                     {'state':'Your ad has been successfull created.'},
                                     context_instance = RequestContext(request),)
    else:
        formset = newAdFormSet()
    return render_to_response('ad_form.html',
                             {'form':formset},
                             context_instance=RequestContext(request),)
```

It works but it always returns one prefilled form for each existing tuple plus, at the end, a blank form.
Now, i can't get how to say where it must return a blank form (to perform a new insert), and where it must instead return a single prefilled form (possibly passing the Ad's id) to perform an update.

Comment: check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what your actual question is. What's happening that shouldn't be?

Comment: okm, i did check that page more than once even before to post my question here, and i didn't find any answer...

Comment: Daniel, i try to explain better:
what i'm getting now is a pege with "x" forms where "x" is the number of forms for each object that i've already inserted into that table of the db.

What i need is:
1) a way to get only 1 blank form to add 1 new item into the database;
2) a way to give the PK to the form so that it could be used to update the object corresponding to that PK...the form should in this case contain the data from the db as initial value...

Don't know how to explain better than this.
Thanks :)

Comment: You could type @o in comment box and an auto-complete hint like @okm will pop up, click it your will notify me then.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, this is only to notify you the reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

modelformset_factory and formset helps to solve a lot, take your code for example

```
def newAd(request):
    newAdFormSet = modelformset_factory(Ad, extra=1)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = newAdFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return render_to_response('conf.html',
                                     {'state':'Your ad has been successfull created.'},
                                     context_instance = RequestContext(request),)
    else:
        formset = newAdFormSet(queryset=Ad.objects.all())
    return render_to_response('ad_form.html',
                             {'form':formset},
                             context_instance=RequestContext(request),)
```

Note the `extra=1` in modelformset_factory line, it ensures there is only one extra blank form. And `queryset=Ad.objects.all()` in the second newAdFormSet inside else statement, it pre-fills forms for Ad objects from DB and correctly set PK in, mostly hidden, field for backend code to recognize submitted objects.

*update*

if you want to set `Ad().codU` to point to an `User()` instance, request.user for example, you could simply just set it by

```
instances = formset.save(commit=False)
for obj in instances:
    obj.codU = request.user
    obj.save()
```

Comment: Ok, with "formset = AdFormSet(queryset=Ad.objects.all().filter(codU=request.user, id=idArt))" in the second else, i now can call one exact object (passing the idArt on the URL) and update it (the imagefield doesn't update correctly but i will fix it later on). I now miss the "blank form only" part: if i don't pass any id on the URL, it should return a blank form i guess? But it returns only a blank page instead...

Comment: @l736k formset here is for editing multiple Ad instances, thus no id is required in the view. Not sure what you mean in `pass any id`. If you mean for `queryset=Ad.objects.filter(codU=request.user, id=idArt)` the view returned an blank page, then check other parts of  your view and template. the formset part should cause one blank form to be rendered

Comment: my mistake: extra was set to 0. i solved adding "if idArt is None: AdFormSet = modelformset_factory(Ad, extra=1) else: AdFormSet = modelformset_factory(Ad, extra=0)". now, maybe you can help me also with the imagefield? from the admin it works, from the formset it doesn't...if you prefer i'll open a new question...

Comment: @l736k it's better to start a new question for it and answers to be more specific

Comment: thanks for your time. can you tell me the last thing? codU is the fk to the User class, off course an user shouldn't see that field. Now, i know how to hide it, but how can i auto populate it with the proper fk? The proper fk is the username...i tried something like "if formset.is_valid(): formset.codU=request.user formset.save()" but it didin't go...i even tried to add something like this in the models "codU = models.ForeignKey(User, default=User)" but it didn't go as well...

Comment: @l736k see answer update. Just as I said, better to start a new question. In that case the question could be more specific to be addressed and answered; more people can see your question and help to find solutions; people who have similar question later, will spot the question easily. So use SO in its most valuable way =)

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not 100% clear what your question is, but it sounds like you don't want a formset at all. If you're only interested in adding or updating a single record at a time, you want a simple `ModelForm`, not a formset. So:

```
class AdForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ad


def add_update_ad(request, pk=None):
    if pk is not None:
        instance = Ad.objects.get(pk=pk)
    else:
        instance = Ad()

    if request.POST:
        form = AdForm(request.POST, instance=instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_instance = form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('my_confirmation_view')
    else:
        form = AdForm(instance=instance)
    return render(request, 'ad_form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: it returns:
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 'str' object is not callable
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in get_response, line 111

Comment: That's not very helpful. Which line in the above code is causing the exception?

Comment: this one: "form = AdForm(instance=instance)"

Comment: Daniel, i've fixed the issue. Just one more question...i should hide "codU" field and automatically populate it with the foreign key to the user class (the username)...do you have any idea?
Also, it doesn't load images...